# Rails ActiveRecord Seems to Forget My PG Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pg

I have a schema, lets call it 'forgotten' schema, and rails seems to recognize and use it fine for about a couple hours, but then for reasons unknown to me, I start getting errors like these:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  schema "forgotten" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "forgotten"."stuff"

ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  schema "forgotten" does not exist
LINE 1: ...COUNT(DISTINCT "forgotten"."other_stuff"."id") FROM "forgotten"."oth...
```

Almost like rails forgot that my schema existed.

My database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: UTF8
  username: xxxxxx
  host: xxxxx
  database: xxxxx
  password: xxxxx
```

I wish it was as easy as adding:

```
schema_search_path: 'forgotten, public'
```

But I get the same results.

Other parts of my app use the public tables with no problem once this starts happening, just not any that use the non public schemas. The only way to get this working again is to restart nginx / passenger. Then things work fine for a couple hours again, until the schema troubles start up again.

So I wish to defer to developers who hopefully have run into and solved this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the following has solved my problem:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database> SET search_path = forgotten, public;
```

Since this command is at the top of the PG precedence for the schema search path this should be a permanent solution. I just added it to a migration.